# Replace html button element with text after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, modal-dialog

I have a button in the main page which on clicking opens a modal. I have a form in the modal with a button which, on submitting closes the modal and returns to the main page. I want to change the html button which is on the main page after closing the modal to plain text. How would I replace the main button in main page after the modal is closed ?

```js
function submitForm() {
  alert('yes');
  var button = document.getElementById('mainButton');
  button.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="mainButton"> Click here </button>
  <div class="modal">
    <form onsubmit="submitForm()">
      <input type="text">
      <button> Done </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

I tried the following in submitForm function:

removing the button like this:

document.getElementById('mainButton').innerHTML = '';

Also tried:
document.getElementById('mainButton').style.display = 'none'

Comment: What you already did and what went wrong? Please, give us your code and we'll help you to solve this issue.

Comment: Make a hidden div with plain text and in submitForm() hide the button and show the div.

Comment: FYI - it's `.innerHTML`, not `.innerHtml `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with a `submit` button (that's the default type of button you get with `<button>`). So, when you click it, the `onsubmit` event handler fires and the form submits, which results in the current page being unloaded, so trying to display anything else isn't going to work.

In this scenario, you'd need the form to redirect to another page that has the content you want on it (that is done by configuring the `form` element's `action` attribute.

---

If you don't really need to submit data to a server, then you can change the type of button you have to a regular `button` and change the event handler to handle just a `click` event and then just take what you are already doing to the next level.

In addition to hiding what you no longer want to see with `display:none`, you can show something that is set up ahead of time and defaulted to `display:none` and then change it to `display:block` when it's time to show it.

```js
function submitForm() {
  alert('yes');
  var button = document.getElementById('mainButton');
  button.style.display = 'none';
  
  // Remove the class that hides the element that you want to now see
  document.querySelector(".afterClick").classList.remove("afterClick");
}
```

```css
.afterClick { display:none; } /* Defaults to hidden */
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="mainButton"> Click here </button>
  <div class="afterClick">Thanks!</div>
  <div class="modal">
    <form onclick="submitForm()">
      <input type="text">
      <button type="button"> Done </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: when I'm adding onclick for form, it is rendering before I enter anything in input field

Comment: @yer That's because as soon as you click anywhere in the form, the handler runs. Don't add the `click` to the form, add it to the button that should trigger all of this just as I'm showing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to replace your button with a div containing its text.

```
var mainButton = document.getElementById('mainButton');
var buttonText = mainButton.textContent;

var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.textContent = buttonText;

document.body.removeChild(mainButton);
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: this seems to be not working, when closing the modal, the main page is not being refreshed. the modal is just closed.